# git permission changed pycharm compare with branch

Tags: git

I have a project on git. In one of the commit I changed the permissions of all the files recursively and I did

```
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
git push origin master
```

Now When I select the Main Repository and use the feature of Pycharm VCS Git
(Compare With Branch)

Now it shows all the files are changed and when I see those files I see that contents are identical.The only difference between the files is that only permission has changed and seeing that commit where I changed permission on gitlab shows that

```
File mode changed from 100644 to 100755
```

Now What I am trying is to change my current permissions to those old permissions and make a new commit, So that next time when I compare with branch, it will show non permission related changes only.

Comment: You need to remove the executeable bit from the files again (don't remove it from the directories), you can do this with `chmod -x file1 file2 file3 ...`

Comment: can you explain a little?Which files.